# To do list is being stored in local storage,but not staying on browser after refresh

Tags: javascript

I have created a to-do app, but for some reason, the list is stored in local storage, but when I refresh the browser the list refuses to stay on the browser after the refresh.

I have not done any CSS just yet I only have the HTML and JS so far

HTML

```
<div class="form">
 <input class ="user-input" type="text">
 <input class="date" type="date">
 <input class="time" type="time">
 <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

JS

```
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

function makeNewTask() {
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };

  return data;
}

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
function display() {
  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  data = makeNewTask();

  let newtask = tasks.innerHTML = `
         <div class="task-content">
          <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
          <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
          <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
          <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
      </div>
  
      <div class="action-buttons">
          <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
          <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
          <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
      </div>
  </div>`;

  taskList.push(data);
  console.log(taskList);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  storeList();
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
  display();
  
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
  window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.

function deleteItem() {
  let removeitem = document.querySelector(".task-content");
  removeitem.parentNode.removeChild(removeitem);
  window.localStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
}

//function that removes stored task when deleted.

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem() {}

//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event) {
  const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
  console.log(element);
  let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
  // style..
  taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

I am not sure how to make it stay on the browser after a refresh. I even added `window.localStorage` hoping that would do the trick.

[image: List on browser]
[image: Page on refresh]

Comment: Please provide the full HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Hey @Mina, I updated my code, there is no CSS yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You localStorage is not empty, according to your second screenshot, problem is that you simply not rendering the data that's already in localStorage

```
renderList(taskList) // renders existing tasks from localStorage

function display() {
 
  data = makeNewTask();

  taskList.push(data); // add new task to list
  renderList(taskList); // render list items
  storeList();
}
// render all items

function renderList (list) {

    list.forEach(function (data) {
      const tasks = document.createElement("div");
      let newtask = tasks.innerHTML = `
         <div class="task-content">
          <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
          <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
          <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
          <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
      </div>
  
      <div class="action-buttons">
          <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
          <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
          <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
      </div>
  </div>`;
       el.list.appendChild(tasks);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I saw in your message I must now update my ```function addTask()```?